# How to give Edit access to files to non-system admin users?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, files

Purpose for this access is because the super users want to edit the File names to a proper naming convention that were uploaded in the Opportunity object.

**Permission sets I tried to assign:**

1. App Permissions :

   - Manage record types and layouts for Files
   - Manage Content Permissions
2. Modify ALL in Opportunity object (since the related Files is attached to Opportunity)
3. Object Settings for Files -> Tab = Default On (Files have no Read,Edit,Modify all permission)

All the above weren't successful.

**File permission I want :**

[image: System Admin File Permission view]

**File Permission I get instead :**

[image: Non-System Admin View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to Salesforce support. I was told that I needed to enable the setting at `Setup > Salesforce Files > General Settings >  Set file access to Set by Record for files attached to records`

[image: Salesforce Files Settings]

Enabling this will automatically give roles higher up the hierarchy of the record owner access to edit the Files uploaded by record owner.

However the huge catch is, this Edit file access to non-system admin users will only apply to files uploaded **AFTER the setting was enabled**.

Answer (score 0):

you can share the file with an unlisted chatter group and make the group a collaborator of the file

file sharing options
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_sharing_groups.htm&type=5

Collaborator can edit
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_settings_perms.htm&type=5

Comment: Interesting hack. Though I'm looking for a more permanent solution that doesn't involve me sharing files 1 by 1. I can't be doing this for 1000s of files

Comment: can always create automation to publish the file to chatter group automatically